# Rails validates uniqueness cross models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: `event.rb` and `bag.rb`
An event has an attribute called `slug` and a bag has an attribute called `bag_code`.

I generate a view based on the `bag_code` attribute. E.g. if the bag-code is "4711" I load records based on that code.

Now for some occasions, a user can define a slug URL in an event and in this case it should overwrite the bag-code.
What I don't want is that a user can choose a `slug` with a value which is already a bag_code (in this case it should be forbidden to choose the `slug` "4711") as this would cause troubles in my view, so it has to be **unique in two models attributes**.

I tried to solve this via scope

```
validates_uniqueness_of :slug, scope: [:bag_code]
```

but that would only work within the same model.

The association between my models is:

`event.rb`

```
has_many :bags
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom validation method would work for this case. Here is how you would set it up:

**event.rb**

```
validates :slug, uniqueness: true
validate :slug_is_unique_from_bag_codes

private

def slug_is_unique_from_bag_codes
  if Bag.find_by bag_code: slug
    errors.add :base, "The slug is already being used as a bag code"
  end
end
```